# Creating an Array with different number of columns in R

Tags: arrays, r

This does not seem possible, so my guess is I am thinking of how to handle my data incorrectly, not simply that I can't find a way to handle it the way I envision. 
I wanted to create a 3-dimensional array; I am thinking of this like a relational database. All dimensions would have the same number of rows, but they have different number of columns. 
For example,

- dimension 1 = 1 column, 20 unique location identifiers (rows)
- dimension 2 = 3 columns of abiotic variables associated with the 20 unique locations (rows)
- dimension 3 = 2 columns of biotic variables associated with the 20 unique locations (rows)

I was thinking this would be the best way to set up my data so that I could go through each column easily and combine within abiotic or biotic easily just using subscripting (e.g., I could apply a function across all varibles (columns) in the 2nd (abiotic) dimension (e.g., dat[,,2] = log(dat[,,2]), which might be different than something I want to do to all biotic variables.

This is a not a treatment group type of analysis, so I don't want stacked data (where I repeat the unique locations 5 times with multiple treatment options for each location - that makes no sense to me for these data, e.g.,

```
loc   type   var
1      ab     1
1      ab     2
1      ab     3
1      bi     1
1      bi     2
```

I am frozen in the way I am thinking about these data. In the past I've always used arrays and the subscripting is so intuitive to me. Can you indeed make an array that has different number of columns in each dimension? If not, what am I missing about how to handle these data? 
Thanks for any thoughts.

Comment: Why is dimension 1 its own thing? I don't understand what kind of function you might apply to 20 unique location identifiers (1:20?) that you would not want to affect the other dimensions with the same unique locations. It looks like a wide or long data.frame to me. data.frame(loc,ab1,ab2,ab3,bi1,bi2) with 20 rows or the long version you don't want. Index your two variable types if you want ab <- c(2,3,4) and use apply(df[,ab],2,fun) to apply a function to only abiotic variables. Otherwise, a list of all 3 with separate data.frame/matrix might work.

Comment: @BrodieG, I think *I* accidentally deleted your comment. Apologies - I'm not usually so clumsy. I think perhaps I just taught myself using arrays, and now it is time to branch out. This just becomes a veryyyyyyy long dataset; I find arrays more compact. I'll redo this with a data table. Thanks!

Comment: @ARobertson, for example, the biotic data are clearly log distributed, whereas the abiotic are not. But more importantly, this is all to do a set or "robustness" tests where we walk through all combinations of various "metrics" by "type", and for me, I can do that easily with a couple of for loops on the dimensions and the variables. I'm sure it can be done using a table, but it just is not nearly as intuitive to me. A list with separate matrices might be the way to do this, you are right. I'll try that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can do as you are describing with

```
# build a 20 x 3 x 2 array
dat <- array(data, c(20,3,2))
# example of applying functions on a given dimension
log(dat[,,2])
```

There is no requirement that the dimensions of the array be equally sized.

Comment: No, but the number of columns in your example, for both 3rd dimensions, is 3. I need the first third dimension to have one matrix of 20x3 and the second third-dimension to have 20x2. I can't do that with an array. These are being sized on-the-fly based on user interface choice, so I think list with separate matrices is the way to go. Thanks